# Parallel Make in OMNET++ Eclipse IDE

Tags: makefile, omnet++

When I build my project in the OMNET++ Eclipse IDE, `make` is called automatically either like `make MODE=release` or `make MODE=debug`. How can I add another argument into make such as `-j4` to enable parallel build.

P.S. I know that in the 'C/C++ Build | Builder Settings' I can uncheck 'Use default build command' and write my own, but I would loose the automatic selection of MODE=release or MODE=debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C/C++ Build` there is `Behavior` tab where one can check `Enable parallel build`. It turns on parallel make without loosing an automatic selection of mode.